# How to add access-control-allow-methods to method in C# POST

Tags: c#, silverlight, post, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to sending a POST to a java web-service with my windows phone app using this c# code:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
                          MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var requestContent = new StringContent(json);
 requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new 
                      MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent);
   //... 
 }
```

but I am getting a 400 Bad Request and sending this header:

```
POST [myreq] HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 340
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: [myhost]
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

and the only difference that I see from a valid similar (to the same web service) android java request is this line in my header:

**access-control-allow-methods=[POST]**

How to include this access-control-allow-methods with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future help

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
```